# Dynamic text qualifier

Tags: excel, sql-server-2008, ssis

I am exporting to `.csv` from SQL Server 2008 so people can use it easily in Excel. I am using SSIS 2008. Otherwise I would just export to Excel. It's about 50 columns, 500K rows so 25M records. The problem is about 40 of those records have a `,` in their data, (records not columns) I added the text qualifier to avoid my columns getting messed up, but that adds 50M `"` marks or about 30 MB (20%) to my output file. I know I could do some type of replace in SQL  Server 2008 but I feel this is going to slow things down a lot.

Is there any way to add a text qualifier only to items with a `,`?

Although thinking about that it would still have to check every record so it seems I am either going to slow my process or screw the end user with a 185MB Excel file.

More info: data source is a stored procedure that takes about four minutes to run all columns are used (SQL Server 2008). Destination is flat file, comma delimited with `"` text qualifier (SSIS 2008).

Comment: If the records are only in certain columns, you can individually switch off the text qualifier per column in the "Advanced" page of the connection manager. Sadly I don't think there's a way to specify qualifiers only on records that need it. Perhaps as pnuts says, a tab-separated format is the way to go. If any fields have tabs, you could replace them with spaces on the way through. (Does the 30MB really matter in the grand scheme of things? It'll get smaller as soon as the user imports it into Excel and saves it as an Excel file, I think, and 30MB doesn't seem like a lot these days...)

Comment: @MattGibson I agree, that 30 MB doesn't seem like a lot but it I am converting over from an "old" method so when they see the file size jump from 140MB to 170MB and open "slower" they will be questioning me. I am going to go with the method of simply adding text qualifiers on the columns with issues. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

To close out this question. We could not determine a way to dynamically add text qualifiers without adding either a script step to the SSIS package or check each fields for the `,` and encapsulate any that have with double `"`. Logically this is what I was excepting but I wasn't sure if SSIS might have a feature I didn't know about.

My final solution was to set any column that could possibly have a comma to use a text qualifier. It increased my file size by 5-10% but that was acceptable.